# Connecting mobile with laptop and having "Obtainning IP address..."

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, laptop

My operating system is Windows 7 x64. And I'm using mHotspot Creator software to turn my laptop into a hotspot.

When I am trying to connect from my mobile it's stuck into "Obtaining IP address" phase forever.

Is it any kind of DHCP server problem? How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type `ncpa.cpl` into run.. dialog. That'll show you all interfaces. Select one that have internet connection, if you want to share it with your mobile. Click right mouse button and select `properties`, then on tab `Sharing` select your wireless interface and check `Allow other users...` then apply these settings.

This should share your internet connection and runs a dhcp-server on your wifi interface along with setting an `192.168.1.1` ip address to it. So now your phone'll get ip from `192.168.1.0/24` subnet and will be able to browse on internet or just connect to your pc.

[image]

*There is a possibility that `mHostspot` won't work with this settings. This is a general way of sharing connection.*

Comment: Thanks.. it worked but with mHotspot. I shared the internet connection from the interface with connectiviy. And the created the hotspot from mHotspotCreator with that network inteface.